# SQL Server goes into suspect mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a situation where one of our customer's database goes into suspect mode, and I am looking to understand what we can do to help their situation. Here is some background on the issue.

Our application is a web app hosted on the JBoss. The application is configured for about 500 XA DB connections. This is needed for the high load. From time to time they notice the following error in the logs

```
Logon Error: 17189, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-07-14 09:11:41.32 Logon SQL Server failed with error code 0xc0000000 to spawn a thread to process a new login or connection. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems. [CLIENT: 10.11.210.38] 
...
spid805 Error: 8510, Severity: 20, State: 3.
2017-07-14 09:15:00.89 spid805 Enlist operation failed: 0x8007000e(Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.). SQL Server could not register with Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) as a resource manager for this transaction. The transaction may have been stopped by the client or the resource manager.
...
2017-07-14 09:15:17.10 Server Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 226.
2017-07-14 09:15:17.10 Server There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
```

And the database restarts, and goes into Suspect mode. After some digging, it appears that this could be related to the following bug,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/890425/you-receive-a-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operati

Also, we recommended the following configuration in the database. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179586%28v%3Dsql.110%29.aspx

The idea here was that even though the database goes down, it would come up automatically without any intervention. But this does not seem to work either.

I am not a database expert, nor do I have access Microsoft support to get more help on this, so I hope somebody can point me in the right direction for this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you verified the server isn't running into actual resource problems? A lack of memory to spawn threads *would* lead to an unstable server, even if databases do not actually end up corrupted (that is, a `DBCC CHECKDB` with `REPAIR` takes it back to `ONLINE` with no actual repair actions). The only permanent solution for that would be a beefier server (possibly with an upgrade for Windows). This should be fairly easy to diagnose because the event log will likely fill up with errors from other components running into allocation issues.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbak, I will look into the server to see if we spot anything.

Comment: This is right (I am working with Poorav): the `DBCC CHECKDB` with `REPAIR` takes the database back to `ONLINE` without any actions.

Comment: XA transactions require activation of a n additional service `MS DTC`, MS Sqlserver and MS DTC are communicating to handle the XA transactions. The error `Enlist operation failed: 0x8007000e(Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.). SQL Server could not register....` could be related to [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/890425/you-receive-a-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operati] : A limitation in windows RPC? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, due to heavy load and heavy uses this error occurs occasionally. Officially Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products, but you can follow the manual methods to fix this error.

Step one: Put your database in Emergency mode.
`ALTER DATABASE  dbName  SET  EMERGENCY`

Step two: Set your database in Single_user  mode.

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Step three: Repair the database.

```
DBCC CHECKDB (dbName, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
```

Note: Repair_allow_data_loss can lead to the cause of data loss from repaired data.

Step four: Put your database to Multi_user mode

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET MULTI_USER
```

Step Five: now it's time to make it Online.

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET ONLINE
```

Thanks